# Is global_asm(include_str("cpu.s")) safe?

Tags: rust

I couldn't find any answers to this. I want to include assembly in my Rust, and I obviously know that inline assembly is not safe.

Is including an assembly file (say "cpu.S") like this safe? `global_asm!(include_str!("cpu.S"))`

Comment: Why should this be different? For compiler you `include_str!` resolves to actual string content. It is no different from using asm code directly as literal.